# Drupal Blog Search

Tags: search

I am using drupal 7. I made site global search with blog content. But it searches only based on the title not for the content of the blog. Else then the blog content type, the other content type values(Title and body description) are searched

The blog content type body only not searched. Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. Are you using the Search module? If it so, it does search in the node body content too.

Comment: I have used the search module. It searches the title of the blog not for the content. This is my problem